# Appropriate follow-up after an initial interview offer and no response to my reply?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, student, first-job, part-time

So, I'm a student and I was recently offered an interview for a part-time job that I am really interested in, but for scheduling reasons could not commit to the time (minimum # of months) that the employers require, and wouldn't want to burn the bridge by quitting early as I anticipate I'd have to.

I replied to the interview offer (email) by stating my interest and my interview availability, offering up an alternative proposal of how I could fulfill the minimum time requirement, and closing with a statement saying I understood if it wouldn't be possible for me to work the time that way and that I would reapply later if that was the case. However, I haven't recieved a reply at all to my email, and it's been several days. I'm worried because the date I said I'd be available to interview on is coming up, and I don't want to be presumptous, but I have no clue if I'm supposed to show or not...

I'm wondering, should I follow up my unanswered email with another email tonight (or a phone call tomorrow, but I feel I'm a better writer than speaker) concerning this? If so, what would be appropriate to say?

**Edit: I want to be clear that I have not yet interviewed. I have not even gotten a confirmation for my possible interview times. The job that was described to be was communicated via email, with the invitation to come in for an in-person interview, and I replied describing my conflicts and alternate proposals and have not recieved a response, so I don't know if or how to find out if the initial invitation to interview still stands. The question that this was flagged as a possible duplicate for concerns the status of a job offer following an interview; I'm trying to figure out if I'm even eligible.**

Comment: Give it a day or two, people are busy and sometimes don't reply back. Follow the advice in the linked discussion.

Comment: "I have no clue if I'm supposed to show or not" - No, you're not supposed to show up on a date you proposed if there was no confirmation from their side, for an interview or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give them a call. Your mail may have been misleading when you wrote "that you would reapply later". There is no protocol forbidding you to contact them an clear up the status. If they wanted to see you before they will either:

1. Still want to see you.
2. Not want to see you anymore, because you can not match their time requirement.
3. Need time to find out if they can still use you.

Either way, a phone call is the fastest way to clear up any ambiguities and even set a positive tone on what could have been a misunderstood e-mail.